# Only returning value if .includes() finds something using .find()

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have this function set up, consuming a Google Maps API response:

```
 zipCode: addressObject.address_components.find((component) =>
          component.types.includes("postal_code")
        ).long_name,
```

However, the `postal_code` is not in the `types`, so how do I only retrieve the `long_name` when the `types` array includes `postal_code`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [optional chaining (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator to get `undefined` when no item is found:

```
zipCode: addressObject.address_components.find((component) =>
  component.types.includes("postal_code")
)?.long_name,
```